# Resize window size using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Hi I want to know how to re size the window border which is launched by running an application 
using VBScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the two commands in this short sub

```
  Sub Window_Onload
     window.moveTo 1030,110'          Moves the window position
 '                                    horizontally, vertically and
     window.resizeTo 225,175'         changes the width and height
  End Sub'  65+450=515  1280-515=765' of the window
```

Answer (score 0):

This example shows an Internet explorer window, moved to top left corner, and resized to 800x1000 pixel.

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Navigate "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390261/resize-window-size-using-vbscript"
IE.Visible = True 
IE.Left=0
IE.Top=0
IE.Width=800
IE.Height=1000
```

The window border depends on what windows theme used by you.