# Advanced VBScript Message/Input Box

Tags: vbscript, inputbox, msgbox

First post here, and would love some help.

### TL;DR

Try to learn to code (first project on my own, simple please). Making autorun message box through VBS. Any help appreciated, currently stuck on changing box size. Tell me if there's a better/simpler way to do this. Trying to learn, please don't just paste an answer (unless you explain it to me, but I still want to figure out myself).

If you can code, but don't know VBS, this Instructables is really helpful. http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Ultimate-VBS-Tutorial/

```
   Call msgbox ("You've found my flash drive!" & chr(13) & "Please return this flash drive to the rightful owner. My contact info is below." ,32+16+256+4096,"You've found my flash drive!")
```

### Full Explaination

So, to start, I can't code. I hate it. But, I need to do something fancy and no better time to learn. If you can, be thoroughly. I've made Pong in Python through a class, but that's it.

The project is to make an autorun message box to load whenever someone plugs in my flash drive. My normal drive was recently lost/stolen, so I want to make a fancy message with contact info and a warning. I want it to let them know that finding the drive and not returning it is illegal, and that they have no use for it (encrypted).

Also, I don't want to waste anyone's time, but try not to do the work for me. This is a learning project, and I want to make coding bearable for myself.

This is what I have so far. Currently stuck on changing the box size. So far just a message box, but if you're going to redo all my code, make it an input box. I know that in coding there are 100s of ways to do something. If there's a better way, teach me. I can do the actually message myself, so this is just barebones for now.

If you can code, but don't know VBS, this Instructables is really helpful. http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Ultimate-VBS-Tutorial/

```
Call msgbox ("You've found my flash drive!" & chr(13) & "Please return this flash drive to the rightful owner. My contact info is below." ,32+16+256+4096,"You've found my flash drive!")
```

Comment: VBScript builtin dialogs aren't cusotmizable that way. You need to create your own custom dialog (e.g. via the Internet Explorer COM object).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I don't understand any of that... I mean people have been able to do stuff like this (see below) with VBS.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c5360549-a068-4199-a178-970ff4247cf8/msgbox-size-and-position?forum=Vsexpressvb

Comment: And @AnsgarWiechers, is there like a generic Windows dialog box that I could make? I don't want it to like open in IE. Just looking for really basic.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Nevermind, this is all I wanted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390261/resize-window-size-using-vbscript

Comment: The code from your last link requires either the IE COM object or a HTA (which also uses the IE engine). The code from your first link is VB, not VBScript.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Still confused. If you had the same project, what language would you use? Then I can just go Google.

Comment: Frankly, I wouldn't do that kind of project in the first place. If I lost an USB stick I'd simply buy a new one, particularly if all the data on it were encrypted. Besides, autorun is a dangerous "feature" that should be disabled on any computer. Period.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Well, true... it's partially just a cool learning experience, and kind of useful. 

One more question for you though. I've started writing the program again, using VB this time. I want an input box for the user to enter a password. Every tutorial uses some sort of input (button press, etc.) to pull up the input box. Is there anyway to just have the input box without needing an input?

Code: https://paste.ubuntu.com/26476813/

Comment: That's a different question, so please post it as a new question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Deal